# Reemplazar caracteres en un rango dado

Tags: javascript, regex

Requiero reemplazar caracteres en un rango especifico, para este ejemplo:

Desde el caracter 0-4 quedan intactos luego sería en reversa, -4

```
var transaction = '1234567890987651907';
//Result 1234****1907
```

**Solución:**
Ya he solucionado lo que buscaba y el codigo es el siguiente.

```
var str = "1234567895555556541";
str.replace(/^(\d{0,4})(\d{4})(.*)/gi,"$1 **** $2");
//result "1234 **** 6541"
```

Comment: no queda claro "en reversa". Quieres que dado 1234567 te devuelve a partir de 5 todo en sentido contrario, es decir 1234765? Por favor dale a [edit] para proporcionar un [mcve], sin asteriscos.

Comment: @Julio la solución fué publicada.

Comment: @Arcaela, OK, pensaba que tenías que preservar el mismo número de asteriscos que de números intermedios. Puedes agregar tu mismo una respuesta a tu pregunta y aceptarla (la propia pregunta no es el lugar adecuado para escribir las soluciones) Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mí me ha funcionado así

```
var str = "1234567895555556541";
str.replace(/^(\d{0,4})(\d{4,7})/gi,"$1 **** ");
//result 1234 **** 55556541
```

Espero que fuese lo que estabas buscando :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
^(\d{4})|\d?\d?(\d{4}$)|(\d)
```

Remplazar por:

```
$1*$2
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/BNkHD6/1/)

Y una demo con javascript aquí mismo:

```js
var regex = /^(\d{4})|\d?\d?(\d{4}$)|(\d)/g;

var pruebas = [
  '1234567895555556541',
  '12349879879879869698698689689698698698697890',
  '1234567890'
];

pruebas.forEach(x => console.log(x.replace(regex, '$1*$2')));
```